# Does imageoptim produce a smaller IPA than Xcode's version of pngcrush?

Tags: ios, xcode, image, png, pngcrush

[imageoptim claim](https://imageoptim.com/xcode.html) to make smaller pngs than Xcodes does, but I don't understand why Xcode wouldn't just use imageoptim instead if it was better.

Does anyone have some data on `imageoptim` pngs vrs xcode's PNG compression size and iOS load time?

Comment: Xcode's pngcrush is not the real pngcrush (which I wrote).  It does some other transformations added by Apple, that cause it to write output that is not a valid PNG (is a CgBI file instead).

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson - Oh - I didn't know that! I have updated the question to reflect that (sorry).  Do you know if the loading step to convert RGBA to premultiplied BGRA is a trivial step as the `imageoptim` site suggests?  Would you suggest using `ImageOptim` for extra compression or leaving xcode's default compression on?

Comment: Also just saw that `imageoptim` is a suite of tools that includes `pngcrush`.

Comment: I would simply suggest running your own experiments.  Note that if you publish any xcode-optimized PNGs, the aren't really PNGs, and people will come complaining to me about them.  Use "pngdefry" to convert them back to real PNGs.

Comment: Xcode makes use of a special delivery codec type of PNG internally. It is not the most compressed possible format though, if you want to take a look at an iOS optimized visually lossless delivery codec, have a look at this SO answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40255615/763355